# Understanding JavaScript Mode Function

Tags: javascript, logic

Through contributions, I've managed to find code that writes a function to find the mode of a given set of numbers. I'm trying to understand exactly what the function does but I am stuck in 1 section of the function.

I tried console logging everything but I couldn't understand 1 part.

After we sort the numbers in an array by their appearances, we use another loop to get the key value of the number that appears the most. Before that, we declare the variables compare and set it to 0 and an empty mode variable.

The part I can't grasp my head around is understanding why we need to compare `freq[item]` to the compare variable and if that statement is true, we need to set compare to `freq[item]`.

Can someone be as kind to explain exactly what is going on there?

Cheers.

```js
function getMostFrequent(arr) {
  var freq = {}
  
  for (item of arr) {
    freq[item] ? freq[item]++ : freq[item] = 1
  }  
  
  var compare = 0
  var mode
  
  for (item in freq) {
    if (freq[item] > compare) {
      compare = freq[item]
      mode = item
    }
  }
  console.log(parseInt(mode))
}

getMostFrequent([1,1,3,3,2,2,5,5,5,3,3,3,3]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the comments bellow. hope it helps.

```
function getMostFrequent(arr) {

  // freq starts empty
  var freq = {}

  // then we start to check every item on arr, our data
  for (item of arr) {

    // is there any attribute on freq called item? 
    // ex: freq[2] is there?
    // if yes, increment it.
    // if not, set it to 1, it's the first time we met him.
    freq[item] ? freq[item]++ : freq[item] = 1
  }  

  // compare starts at the lowest value,
  // assuming only positive numbers. 
  var compare = 0

  // we don't know the mode yet. keep it undefined.
  var mode

  // now we loop every attribute present in freq. 
  for (item in freq) {

    // have we counted freq[item] more times 
    // than the actual value  of compare? 
    if (freq[item] > compare) {
      // if yes, we store that number on compare
      compare = freq[item]
      // also, item (which is a number too!) is, as far as we know,
      // our mode. 
      mode = item
    }

    // loop shall repeat untill we check every atribute inside freq 
  }

  // and finally we print mode, since it must the the mode
  console.log(parseInt(mode))
}

// call the function passing sample data
getMostFrequent([1,1,3,3,2,2,5,5,5,3,3,3,3]);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the part you’re referring to:

```
var compare = 0;
var mode;

for (item in freq) {
  if (freq[item] > compare) {
    compare = freq[item];
    mode = item;
  }
}
```

This computes the maximum among all `freq[item]`s. It’s probably better to rename the variable `compare` to `maximum`, since that’s what it’s going to be at the end.

The `if` condition is only true for frequencies (`freq[item]`) that are larger than that maximum, so `compare` is being set to that bigger frequency value. In other words, `compare` is the maximum `freq[item]` of all `freq[item]`s seen so far.

The final statement will then be `mode = item;` which is only called for the last maximum frequency (which is the maximum overall), which sets the `mode` to the most common `item`.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a case with that line removed as well.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Taurus

Comment: @Xufox I just don't understand how the compare variable knows to return that objects key

Comment: @Taurus Again, what line? What do you mean by “case”?

Comment: the `compare = freq[item]` line, e.g without that line, if you pass `[2, 2, 3]`, `mode` will be set to `3`.

Comment: @Xufox I am using "case" as an English word, not a programming construct or anything.

Comment: @GabrielPozo `compare` isn’t returned. It’s just used to keep track of which key is the maximum number (object value). Then the value that appeared most frequently in the original array of numbers (object key) is logged.

Comment: @Xufox it is a bit odd but the original function returns nothing

Comment: @Taurus _“without that line, if you pass `[2, 2, 3]`, `mode` will be set to `3`”_ —well,  what did you expect? If you remove a crucial step from the logic, the result is going to be wrong. That’s not really a “case”, that’s just a wrong result due to a wrong algorithm.